# How are booleans formatted in Strings in Python?

Tags: python, boolean, string-formatting

I see I can't do:

```
"%b %b" % (True, False)
```

in Python. I guessed `%b` for b(oolean). Is there something like this?

Comment: What do you want the result to be? True and False? You want '%s' then. %b, when it exists, is for binary (as in base-2).

Comment: Ho yes! "%s" seems to work just fine. Reply this question and get a lected answer. I used to do "%s" % str(False). Shame on me :)

Comment: link to relevant documentation:  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 279, accepted):

```
>>> print "%r, %r" % (True, False)
True, False
```

This is not specific to boolean values - `%r` calls the `__repr__` method on the argument.  `%s` (for `str`) should also work.

Comment: What's the major difference between `%r` and `%s`?

Comment: I always had this distiction in mind, but correct me if I'm wrong. %s (and thus str()) aim to represent the object as transparantly as possible for humans. %r (and thus repr()) aim to represent the object as transparantly as possible for python. For example, `print(str("foo"))` merely prints `foo` on a new line. `print(repr("foo"))` however prints `'foo'` on a new line, including the quotes, since that's what you need to type in the python interpreter to get the corresponding object to the argument in python.

Answer (score 81):

If you want `True False` use:

```
"%s %s" % (True, False)
```

because `str(True)` is `'True'` and `str(False)` is `'False'`.

or if you want `1 0` use:

```
"%i %i" % (True, False)
```

because `int(True)` is `1` and `int(False)` is `0`.

Answer (score 21):

You may also use the [Formatter class](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#string-formatting) of string

```
print "{0} {1}".format(True, False);
print "{0:} {1:}".format(True, False);
print "{0:d} {1:d}".format(True, False);
print "{0:f} {1:f}".format(True, False);
print "{0:e} {1:e}".format(True, False);
```

These are the results

```
True False
True False
1 0
1.000000 0.000000
1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

Some of the `%`-format type specifiers (`%r`, `%i`) are not available. For details see the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: Note that adding formatting options [can screw this up.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36573222/241211) E.g. `{:_^5}` will get you `'__1__'` unless you `str(...)` the booleans.

Comment: You can [get around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326865/241211) the problems with type conversions like `!s`: `'{!s:_^5}'.format(True)` is `'True_'`

Answer (score 8):

To update this for Python-3 you can do this

```
"{} {}".format(True, False)
```

However if you want to actually format the string (e.g. add white space), you encounter Python casting the boolean into the underlying C value (i.e. an int), e.g.

```
>>> "{:<8} {}".format(True, False)
'1        False'
```

To get around this you can cast `True` as a string, e.g.

```
>>> "{:<8} {}".format(str(True), False)
'True     False'
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [the answer by phd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60759841/241211), you can do all that without `str()`-ing your booleans in the `format()` call. There are [some weird tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326865/241211) you can exploit to do formatting for booleans with the new style of string interpolation. It also works for f-strings.

#### The bland, trivial case

```py
'{},{}'.format(True, False)  # 'True,False'
f'{True},{False}'            # 'True,False'
```

#### Adding some formatting converts booleans to integers

Any padding length will do this. I am not sure why someone would want it to work this way.

```py
'{:0},{:0}'.format(True, False)  # '1,0'
f'{True:0},{False:0}'            # '1,0'

'{:>5},{:>5}'.format(True, False)  # '    1,    0'
f'{True:>5},{False:>5}'            # '    1,    0'
```

#### [String coercion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) can bring back the normal text

Note the `!s` in there. This is the most direct equivalent to `%s`. There's also `!r` for `__repr__()` and `!a` for ASCII, but they're not particularly interesting for booleans.

```py
'{!s:>5},{!s:>5}'.format(True, False)  # ' True,False'
f'{True!s:>5},{False!s:>5}'            # ' True,False'
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [Python string interpolation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation)

In Python 3.6, string interpolation has been added with a new string literal **f** prefix

```
shouldBeTrue = True
print(f"shouldBeTrue={shouldBeTrue}")
```