# How to control length of the result of string.format(bool_value) in Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

What the equivalent way to `str.format` function for converting booleans into strings?

```
>>> "%5s" % True
' True'

>>> "%5s" % False
'False'
```

Please note the space in `' True'`. This  always makes the length the same for 'True' and 'False'.

I've check the methods in this post:

[How are booleans formatted in Strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259228/how-are-booleans-formatted-in-strings-in-python)

None of them can do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `"{:>5}".format(str(True))` works fine. 
The output is exactly the same as `"%5s" % True`, ie `' True'`.

So the length of `"{:>5}".format(str(bool_value))` is alway 5, no matter `bool_value` is `True` or `False`.

Of course you may change the length or the alignment direction as you want. eg. `"{:6}".format(str(True))` outputs `'True  '`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use type conversion flags to do what you wanted:

```py
'{:_>5}'.format(True)   # Oh no! it's '____1'
'{!s:_>5}'.format(True) # Now we get  '_True'
```

Note the `!s`. I used an underscore to show the padding more clearly. It also works with f-strings:

```py
f'{True:_>5}'   # '____1'
f'{True!s:_>5}' # '_True'
```

#### Relevant documentation:

> ### 6.1.3. [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
>
> [...]
>
> The *conversion* field causes a type coercion before formatting. Normally, the job of formatting a value is done by the [`__format__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) method of the value itself. However, in some cases it is desirable to force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own definition of formatting. By converting the value to a string before calling [`__format__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__), the normal formatting logic is bypassed.
>
> Three conversion flags are currently supported: `'!s'` which calls [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) on the value, `'!r'` which calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and `'!a'` which calls [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii).
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```
> "Harold's a clever {0!s}"        # Calls str() on the argument first
> "Bring out the holy {name!r}"    # Calls repr() on the argument first
> "More {!a}"                      # Calls ascii() on the argument first
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str()` function. More about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Here are some examples:

```
x = str(True)
y = False

print( type(x) )
<class 'str'>   # This is a string

print( type(y) )
<class 'bool'>  # This is a boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got idea correctly but if some variable x results in True or False, You can write str(x); if not a case, sorry just try explaining Q in more detailed way